# Subbundles of a rank-two trivial bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Can every line bundle $\mathcal{O}(a)$ on $ \mathbb{P}^1$ be realized as a subbundle of the trivial bundle $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}$ on  $\mathbb{P}^1$? I know that this phenomena can happen in general: for example Moebius band gives an example of a nontrivial real subbundle of the rank-two real trivial bundle on $S^1$, however I can't think of any meaningful obstruction here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. For every $k > 0$, we have $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k) \cong \mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}$ as smooth bundles over $\mathbb{CP}^1$. To see this, note that

$$\operatorname{rank}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k)) = 4 > 2 = \dim_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{CP}^1,$$

so $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k)$ admits a nowhere-zero section, and hence $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k) \cong L\oplus\mathcal{O}$ for some complex line bundle $L$. As

$$c_1(L) = c_1(L\oplus\mathcal{O}) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k)) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(k)) + c_1(\mathcal{O}(-k)) = 0,$$

and smooth complex line bundles are classified by their first Chern class, we have $L \cong \mathcal{O}$, and hence $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k) \cong L\oplus\mathcal{O} \cong \mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}$.

Note however that $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k)$ and $\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}$ are not isomorphic as holomorphic vector bundles. To see this, note that

$$\Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k)) = \Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}(k))\oplus\Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}(-k)) = \Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}(k))\oplus\{0\}.$$

As $\Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}(k))$ can be identified with the set of degree $k$ homogeneous polynomials in two variables, it has dimension $k + 1$.

On the other hand,

$$\Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}) = \Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O})\oplus\Gamma(\mathbb{CP}^1, \mathcal{O}) = \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{CP}^1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{CP}^1) = \mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$$

which has dimension $2$. So for $k \neq 1$, we see that $\mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-k)$ and $\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}$ are not isomorphic as holomorphic vector bundles. I think there should be an easier way of demonstrating this fact which would also include the case $k = 1$, but I can't think of it right now (other than appealing to semistability directly).

Comment: Great! I have a following-up question then. Let's take the subbundle $F = \mathcal{O}(k)$ of $E = \mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}$ from your construction. When is $E / F$ torsion free?

Comment: The quotient of a vector bundle by a subbundle is always a vector bundle, so it is torsion-free (or rather, it's sheaf of sections is).

Comment: How come then $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}$ is a semistable vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ if I can construct subbundles of arbitrary high slope?

Comment: My answer only deals with isomorphisms of complex vector bundles, not holomorphic bundles. Note, they are not isomorphic as holomorphic bundles. I can add this to my answer if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, I'd be obliged if you could do this. Sorry for not being precise enough in my question - I meant indeed homomorphic bundles.

Comment: Maybe actually the following naïve approach would work: let $U_0, U_1$ be the usual cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $F$ be a subbundle of $E$. Transition functions of them are related as follows $g^E_{UV} = \begin{pmatrix} g^F_{UV} & * \\ 0 & g^{E/F}_{UV}\end{pmatrix}$. However if $E$ is the trivial bundle, then the matrix is simply the identity matrix, forcing both the quotient and subbundle transition functions to be constant equal $1$.

Comment: Every line bundle $\mathcal{O}(a)$ can be realized as a subbundle of the trivial rank two bundle if $a\leq 0$.

Comment: Any proof of that fact? Do you see where both of us are wrong in our proofs?

Comment: Do you know the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and that there is a natural surjection from the trivial bundle onto this? Then, the kernel is a line bundle and easy to see that it is $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. It is now easy to get all $a<0$, by pulling back to a morphism of degree $a$ from the projective line to itself. $a=0$ is of course trivial.

Comment: Dear Michael, for the case $k=1$ just notice that  $\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(-2) \ncong\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-1) $ (because the first bundle has non-zero holomorphic functions while the second hasn't) so that twisting by $\mathcal O(1)$ you obtain the desired non-isomorphism $\mathcal O(1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-1) \ncong \mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Very nice!

Comment: @StephenDedalus: Just to be clear, Mohan's comments do not contradict my answer as they are referring to holomorphic subbundles. So for $k > 0$, the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(k)$ is a complex subbundle of $\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}$, but not a holomorphic subbundle.